# IIViewDeck + KNSemiModal error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use these two libraries with a custom button in my KNSemiModal subview to dismiss it.  When I call

```
UIViewController * parent = [self.view containingViewController];
if ([parent respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissSemiModalView)]) {
    [parent dismissSemiModalView];
}
```

I git (pun on accident, wow) this error:

```
Defaults must have been set when accessing options
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is parent isn't the actual view that originally showed the view.  It's picking up something from IIViewDeck.

So, instead, make it easy to grab a reference to the original parent view.  Lots of ways to fix this (delegate in the subview, singleton, etc.).  I went with a dirty method of just setting the parent on the child explicitly.  Add this property to your subview:

```
@property UIViewController *customParent;
```

Then just set it before you bring the view to life:

```
- (IBAction)onButtonTouch:(UIButton *)button {
    NSLog(@"Touch");
    semiVC.customParent = self;

    [self presentSemiViewController:semiVC withOptions:@{
                                                         KNSemiModalOptionKeys.pushParentBack    : @(NO),
                                                         KNSemiModalOptionKeys.animationDuration : @(.6),
                                                         KNSemiModalOptionKeys.shadowOpacity     : @(0.3),
                                                         }];

}
```

and finally use it when you want to close in the subview:

```
- (IBAction)onCloseTap:(id)sender {
    [self.customParent dismissSemiModalView];
}
```